# No permissions for postgres extensions in CosmosDB for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure-cosmosdb, hasura, postgresql-extensions

I am using CosmosDB for PostgreSQL and I need permissions to `pgcrypto` pg extension with the default "citus" user but don't. I can't give myself access because I can't log in as the default superuser "postgres". If I don't have permissions for extensions, then aren't [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/postgresql/reference-extensions) that say that and `pgcrypto` is listed supported wrong since I don't permissions to use them even if they are installed? Does anyone know how to use pg extensions with CosmosDB for PostgreSQL?

#### Update 1

To give more context, I am using Hasura GraphQL to build the database schema. It is running in an Azure Container Instance and takes the "citus" connection string as an environment variable:

```
HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL="postgres://citus:mypassword@my-cosmos-pg-db.tkgkgkjgkjkj.postgres.cosmos.azure.com:5432/citus?sslmode=require"
```

The Hasura migration functionality is what requires `pgcrypto`. When I run:

```
hasura migrate apply --endpoint http://my-hasura-engine.eastus.azurecontainer.io --admin-secret myadminsecret
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": "query execution failed",
  "path": "$",
  "code": "postgres-error",
  "internal": {
    "arguments": [],
    "error": {
      "description": null,
      "exec_status": "FatalError",
      "hint": null,
      "message": "must be owner of extension pgcrypto",
      "status_code": "42501"
    },
    "prepared": false,
    "statement": "SET check_function_bodies = false;\nCREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto WITH SCHEMA public;\nCOMMENT ON EXTENSION pgcrypto IS 'cryptographic functions';\n"
  }
```

Comment: What’s the exact command that you used? And the exact error message? (Both in plain text)

Comment: @FrankHeikens I added more context and the exact command and error message to the  question.

Comment: Most likely it’s the comment that is the issue since you are not the owner. From the manual: For most kinds of object, only the object's owner can set the comment.

Comment: i was wondering if that was the issue but missed that note in the docs

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and it is working fine for me make sure you also logged in correctly using plsql and default `citus` user only.

In below screenshot you can see that I logged in my **Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL Cluster** with default `citus` user   and when I tried to create `pgcrypto` extension its throwing error as already exist because it is already present.

[image]

If you are getting permission denied error, you can first grant create permission to particular user with that database.

```sql
GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE database_name to username;
```

**With below code I tested it:**

```sql
--create a table users:
CREATE TABLE users (  
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,  
email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,  
password TEXT NO NULL  
);

--Inser encrypted pasword in it
INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (  
'johndoe@mail.com',  
crypt('johnspassword', gen_salt('bf'))  
);
```

**Successful execution:**

[image]

> **Note:- here I connected with by default citus database.**

Comment: I added more context and the exact command and error message to the  question.